# How are collections Shared between two view models in TAB?

Tags: caliburn.micro

I have three view models, using TAB, the shell view model contains a TAB control, contains two view models, and the.tab1 view model contains a collection that changes within the tab1 view.Now I'm trying to get the set in the tab2 view model in real time and I'm trying to get the set in the tab1 view  model, and I'm also changing the set value.How do I do that?

Comment: the question is not clear. could you please add some code.

Comment: Without your code i'll say Event Aggregator could be the solution!... Please add some code